# Условие php если прошло определенное время

Tags: php

Ребят помогите составить условие, допустим у нас есть начальная дата. От начальной даты нужно отсчитать 30 дней вперед и вывести условие. Если же прошло менее 30 дней то ничего не выводим.

```
    if (....) {
    echo 'Выводим если прошло более 30 дней от начальной даты';
} else {
    echo 'Ничего не выводим так как 30 дней еще не прошло';
}
```

Comment: Покажите вашу начальную дату, в каком формате она?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Пример, докрутите сами:

```
if (date_diff(new DateTime(), new DateTime('2018-01-02 00:00:00'))->days > 30) {
    echo 'Прошло больше 30 дней';
}else {
    echo 'Прошло меньше 30 дней';
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$dates = [
    "2018-06-04",
    "2018-05-07"
];

//$expression = '+2 year';
//$expression = '+1 month';
$expression = '+30 days';

foreach($dates as $startDate){
    if(strtotime("{$startDate}{$expression}") < time()){
        echo "Таймаут ({$expression}) '{$startDate}'\n";
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Вот так:

```
// дата окончания: Час Мин Сек Месяц День Год
// к дате/месяцу/году прибавляем сколько нужно
$day_last = mktime(0, 0, 0, 6, 4 + 30, 2018);

// текущая дата
$day_current = mktime(0, 0, 0, date("m"), date("d"), date("Y"));

if ($day_last > $day_current) ... дальше по коду ...
```

Функция mktime() сама определит нужную метку времени и сместит месяц/год с учетом всех факторов, например зимнее/летнее время. При желании можно указать дату с точностью до секунды. В примере они по нулям.